# Problem with reference to subfigure

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, subcaption

So my code seems like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/state_of_art/3dsegm1a.png}
    \caption{Image1.}
    \label{fig:3dsegm1a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}  
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/state_of_art/3dsegm1b.png}
    \caption{Image2.}
    \label{fig:3dsegm1b}   
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Image.} 
\label{fig:3dsegm1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I use `\usepackage{subcaption}` and I compile it with no problem. But when I try something like: `\ref{fig:3dsegm1a}`, I always get a reference to the second image (f.e I get something like "10βʹ" instead of "10αʹ", despite the fact that the letters (α and β) are correct on the figure).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer. It was due to this [bug](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/110) of polyglossia package for Greek language. The solution is `\setmainlanguage[numerals=arabic]{greek}`.